# How can I fix this error ( Laravel 5.7 )?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

When I try to login ?

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (1045) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = andro.nady2015@gmail.com
>   limit 1)

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: Do you using homestead? Or DB exists on local mashine?

Comment: Show us your database.php file.

Comment: @kerbholz  I did it But still have a problem

Comment: @Egretos No I created this database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:-

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

in place of this:-

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone , I solved this problem by download new version of Xampp